# Write emojis to external file

Tags: pdftex, write-file, emoji

There's some way to write to external file emojis and accents characters:

```
%pdflatex or latex compiler
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\emo
\immediate\openout\emo=\jobname.emoji
\immediate\write\emo{

á}
\immediate\closeout\emo
\end{document}
```

Expected content file:

```
á
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works with `lualatex`. But you have to replace the two newlines with `^^J^^J`.

Comment: works with a current latex-dev (the newlines are written as \par).